# Optimal layout for my cluster of space ships?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

### My spaceships need to land but not too close to each other!

For some fiction, I'm planning the spaceships my colonists landed in to be laid out in the below pattern, with a central 'hub'. Each dot (regardless of colour and size) is a ship.

[image: centered triangle pattern, mirrored on the base without duplicating the lowest dots. The central dot is larger than the others. There are two scales; one for the width, and one for the height. These indicate that the height is three times longer than the width.]

I made the pattern by duplicating and mirroring a [centered triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_triangular_number) figure with n=2, and overlapping the lowest 3 dots.

I'm trying to find how large each ships can be while still having an appreciable gap between the two.

Here are my constraints:

1. The length is 3 times the width
2. The gaps between the nearest dots (including the central) are between 1/50th and 1/250th the total width of the layout
3. The central dot is larger than the smaller dots by at least 20%.
4. The gap between the large ship and the outer 'hexagonal ring' of ships is no less than half the distance between two nearest small ships
5. The ships are roughly hexagonal. I don't know if this is important (does it make a different to the vertical/horizontal/diagonal gaps?).

I've attempted to write this out as a set of equations on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6a%2B6b%2Bc%3D3n%2C%204a%2Bb%2Bc%3Dn%2C%20%28n%2F250%29%3Ca%3C%28n%2F50%29%2C%20b%3E0%2C%20c%3E0%2C%20c%3Eb%2C%20c%3E0.5a%2Bb)

$$6a+6b+c=3n$$
$$4a+b+c=n $$
$$(n/250)<a<(n/50), b>0, c>0, c>b, c>0.5a+b$$

Where $a$ is the gap size, $b$ is the smaller ship height and width, and $c$ is the larger ship height and width. The scaling factor is $n$.

Now this seemed sensible to me, but then I realised that I'm going to have to take into account the layout is not square, so I can't directly constrain the diagonal gaps by the length and height of the layout. I've looked at [hexagon parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon#Parameters) which make sense, however I'm at a loss of how to factor this into the above equation. Do I now need a separate number for ship height and width? Are there any other factors I need to take into account so that this is solveable?

If I do need a separate height and width parameters, this might be a useful [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJuiM.png) to reference.

Comment: I believe this is answered in your equations, but just to be clear: The "gaps" you mention are perimeter-to-perimeter distances (as opposed to center-to-center), correct?

Comment: @blue yes it's perimeter to perimeter. But the issue I'm having is that the ships are hexagonal, so I don't know if that messes up the equations or not (because the gaps cannot be the same in all directions).